To configure Chart.js to display hours on the x-axis ticks when rendering charts in a Node.js
i am generating chart image in node using chart js how can i use hours on the ticks is there any idea for that
Error: This method is not implemented: Check that a complete date adapter is provided.
import chartjs - adapter - date - fns from 'chartjs-adapter-date-fns'
var lineChartDetails: ChartConfiguration = {
  type: 'line',
  data: {
    datasets: [{
      label: 'Sample Dataset',
      data: dataPoints,
      borderColor: 'rgb(75, 192, 192)',
      tension: 0.1
    }]
  },
  options: {
    scales: {
      x: {
        type: 'time',
        time: {
          unit: 'day',
          tooltipFormat: 'MMM dd, yyyy'
        }
      }
    },
    plugins: {
      tooltip: {
        callbacks: {
          title: function(tooltipItems) {
            return tooltipItems[0].label;
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
};


Wherever you are registering the chart, make sure that you register TimeScale from Chart.js, and update your import to directly import he entirety of chartjs-adapter-date-fns. Here's how mine is configured:
import { Line } from 'react-chartjs-2';

import {
    TimeScale,
    LinearScale,
    CategoryScale,
    Title,
    PointElement,
    LineElement,
    Tooltip,
    Chart,
    Filler,
} from 'chart.js';
    
import 'chartjs-adapter-date-fns';

Chart.register(
    CategoryScale,
    LinearScale,
    Title,
    PointElement,
    LineElement,
    Tooltip,
    TimeScale,
    Filler,
);

export default Line;


getting error date adapter is not provided and wanr solution for node js server not for react js

But where are you instantiating the chart? These are the configurations options, but we cant see the implementation where you are calling Chart.js. That error suggests that the adapter date fns are not being correctly registered.

wait i will share my whole code how am i generating chart

I ran into this same trouble when I worked with timeseries, so hopefully should be able to help when you do
